# Issue with new data in Project Job Scheduling example

Tags: optaplanner

thanks to your previous answer, I have been able to create a new small example (with two simple projects A and B made by two jobs each A1,A2,B1,B2) in "Project Job scheduling".
The files load correctly but the result is not the expected one.
The result seems to be influenced by the projects files order (in the main txt file)
If I load the project A data before the project B data and run the example I get one result, if I invert the sequence and load B as "first" project and run it, I get a completely different result.

Since this does not make sense, I am sure I am doing something wrong. Could you help me finding out what?
To be precise... if I load AA_j1011_7.mm first I get a total time of 19
while if I load AA_j1011_8.mm as fist file, I get a total time of 15 (which is the expected result, btw)

Under I attach the main txt file and the two related project files (.mm)

Thanks in advance
Alessandro

---

Main File

```
2
0
50
j10.mm/AA_j1011_7.mm
0
50
j10.mm/AA_j1011_8.mm
2
1   1
```

---

AA_j1011_7.mm

```
************************************************************************
file with basedata            : mm11_.bas
initial value random generator: 1182272221
************************************************************************
projects                      :  1
jobs (incl. supersource/sink ):  4
horizon                       :  50
RESOURCES
  - renewable                 :  2   R
  - nonrenewable              :  0   N
  - doubly constrained        :  0   D
************************************************************************
PROJECT INFORMATION:
pronr.  #jobs rel.date duedate tardcost  MPM-Time
    1     2      0       50        0       0
************************************************************************
PRECEDENCE RELATIONS:
jobnr.    #modes  #successors   successors
   1        1          1           2
   2        1          1           3
   3        1          1           4
   4        1          0        
************************************************************************
REQUESTS/DURATIONS:
jobnr. mode duration  R 1  R 2  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      1     0       0    0    
  2      1     6       1    0    
  3      1     6       0    1    
  4      1     0       0    0    
************************************************************************
RESOURCEAVAILABILITIES:
  R 1  R 2  
    1    1 
************************************************************************
```

---

AA_j1011_8.mm

```
************************************************************************
file with basedata            : mm11_.bas
initial value random generator: 1182272221
************************************************************************
projects                      :  1
jobs (incl. supersource/sink ):  4
horizon                       :  50
RESOURCES
  - renewable                 :  2   R
  - nonrenewable              :  0   N
  - doubly constrained        :  0   D
************************************************************************
PROJECT INFORMATION:
pronr.  #jobs rel.date duedate tardcost  MPM-Time
    1     2      0       50        0       0
************************************************************************
PRECEDENCE RELATIONS:
jobnr.    #modes  #successors   successors
   1        1          1           2
   2        1          1           3
   3        1          1           4
   4        1          0        
************************************************************************
REQUESTS/DURATIONS:
jobnr. mode duration  R 1  R 2  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      1     0       0    0    
  2      1     2       1    0    
  3      1     7       0    1    
  4      1     0       0    0    
************************************************************************
RESOURCEAVAILABILITIES:
  R 1  R 2  
    1    1 
************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does make sense, due to the NP-complete/NP-hard nature of planning problems...

[Read this blog about the search space of planning problems](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/27/IsTheSearchSpaceOfAnOptimizationProblemReallyThatBig.html) to grok the understanding. [It's also partially in this chapter in the manual.](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#searchSpaceSize)

If there's 1 optimal solution (sometimes there are multiple) and the algorithms have enough time to reach that (sometimes this takes billions of years, even though they are near optimal in seconds), then indeed it should be the same solution.

Comment: Configure Branch and Bound algorithm in OptaPlanner if you want the optimal solution and your dataset is small enough for it to solve it in reasonable time.

Comment: I was trying the depth first approach but it seems from the manual that is has not been implemented yet... I will try the branch and bound solution (I did not see it in the configuration manual, I will seek for it better) because the set of data in our kind of problems is usually quite small.

Comment: Sorry to steal some more of your time... Downloaded the latest version and configured the branch and bound algo... but the system complains about entitySelector  -->  The entitySelector (Filtering(FromSolutionEntitySelector(Allocation)))'s size (8) is not accurate enough for exhaustive search.

Comment: I believe this is a bug, I am tracking it in [this JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-265) and hoping to fix it for 6.2.0.Beta2. Please watch that jira link for when it's fixed and if there's a workaround.